# Kendo UI template-based menu - how to?

Tags: kendo-ui

In this [Kendo UI menu sample](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/index), if you click on "Stores" you will see a template-based menu. It has a button "See full list" but it doesn't do anything.

Question: how to trigger an action when an element is clicked in a template-based menu? Note that the menu should close after the action is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close the menu on Button cilck as below:

```
 <button onClick="alert('See Full Clicked.'); $('#menu').data('kendoMenu').close();" class="k-button">See full list</button>
```

See the updated Menu example: 
[Updated Kendo Menu sample](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/iCaW/3)